# ASP.NET and C#: hide spinning wheel when button has finished processing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar, visual-studio-2019

In my web form, I have a button, and when users click on it, I show a spinning wheel to signal that the request is being processed:

```
<td class="auto-style1"><asp:LinkButton ID="lblButton" runat="server" OnClick="doSomething">Button</asp:LinkButton></td> 
<td id="load" style="display:none"> <img src="Images/usethiswheel.gif" height="30" width="30" /> </td>
```

To regulate the appearance of the spinning wheel, I am using the following snippet:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#lblButton').click(function () {
    $('#load').show();
    setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 40000);
  });
 });
</script>
```

However, I am using a timeout function expiring after 40 seconds. How can I make the spinning wheel disappear in the exact moment the button has finished processing?

Comment: Does the button click fire an async request?

Comment: I am waiting for a response from an API, so I think it's synchronous.

Comment: Do you make that call in JS?

Comment: No, it's c# code-behind

Comment: So the page refreshes after clicking?

Comment: Yes, so it seems

Comment: In this case there's no way for the first page to know when the request ends as it's been unloaded. The point of the question seems a little moot given the fact the page is redirected anyway; the spinner wiill be removed when the next page loads

Comment: What if the page didn't refresh after clicking?

Comment: Then you would need to change how you make the request so it's async, commonly done with Ajax, and then listen for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ajax calls to wait for response from server, you might need something like this (depends on type of calls you do to serverside) since its c#:

```
       <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lblButton').click(function () {
            $('#load').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SomeMethod", "Somecontroller")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#load').hide();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What should replace "SomeMethod" and "Somecontroller"?

Comment: if your using MVC @Url.Action helps you to specify controller name and method name on which you are making request. otherwise just specify your url for example: `$.ajax({
                url: "http://example.com")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#load').hide();
                }
            });`

Comment: Interesting. If I use this snippet my spinning wheel does not appear at all... while it was before

Comment: try to use inspect F12, switch to Console tab and check what is the error.

Comment: Since i'm not well familiar with aspnet webforms i found this example, hope it will be helpfull.

[calling-asp-net-code-behind-using-jquery-ajax-simple-complete-example](https://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/02/calling-asp-net-code-behind-using-jquery-ajax-simple-complete-example/)

Answer (score 2):

As Davit Mikuchadze says you could try to show the loading gif when using ajax to make

the request to the code-behind(e.g webmethod), then you could hide the gif in the ajax

success function.

But, you could also try to use ajaxtoolkit updatepanel and UpdateProgress control to

achieve your requirement.

About how to install the ajaxtookit control, you could refer to this article 
https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Step-by-Step-Installation-Guide.

The code example:

ASPX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="center">
            <img alt="" src="loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>
            Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: How does System.Threading.Thread.Sleep make sure that the spinning wheel spins for as long as the page is being processed? This line tells me it will only do it for 5 seconds. Am I reading this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

For this you should try as below on completion of ajax call you should hide the spinning wheel.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lblButton').click(function () {
            $('#load').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SomeMethod", "Somecontroller")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#load').hide();
                },
                failure: function(response){
                    $('#load').hide();
                },
                error: function(response){
                    $('#load').hide();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```